# How to Update many documents from array of values and keys and _id

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have DB with some documents inside the document that looks like that and I need to update the default_value and value fieald

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c938b99786ca358570d61fc"),
"status" : "active",
"key" : "driving_calling_number",
"default_value" : "********",
"value" : "********",
"operator" : ObjectId("5c938b96786ca358570d5d61"),
"language" : ObjectId("5c938b96786ca358570d5d64"),
"version" : 0.1,
"createdAt" : ISODate("2019-03-21T13:03:21.375Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-10-07T14:15:35.252Z"),
"__v" : 0
```

}

the array looks like that with _id and new value (in the original array I have more than 1000 new values )

```
[{"_id":"5c938b99786ca358570d61fc","NEW ES VALUE":"+555555555"}]
```

Comment: Have you tried a bulk write operation?

Comment: no, I've not.
from the mongo documentation, I cant understand how it can help me?